# Flutter _ How to fix display error of this keyboard

Tags: flutter, dart

After I clicked on the line to edit the text, my keyboard appeared too high, making the interface look like it was corrupted.

[image: This is picture 1]

[image: This is picture 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by setting the property `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to false.

It works fine.

```
     Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: .....,
      ),
```

Comment: Only one attribute line solved my problem, Thanks very much.

Comment: Remember to mark the answer correct and upvote so others can see the relevance @VinhNguyễn